# Timing constrain the ADC to FPGA data path

Tags: fpga, adc, timing-analysis, sdc

An ADC uses 12 single ended CMOS signals to transfer data to an FPGA. Both of them share 120 MHz source on the PCB. However, the PCB delay from the oscillator to the clock pin of each component is different. Here is the conceptual diagram where the PCB tracks are color coded. There are 12 PCB tracks for the data since the data is transferred parallely.

[image]

I have no clue how to constrain these 12 timing paths. They all involve delay on PCB tracks. How should the user constrain these paths using SDC commands?

Comment: If using Xilinx, do a search on "Xilinx setting input delay".

Comment: You have to define the min and max delay of the 12 paths data transition versus the FPGA clock input. This can be found using the datasheet of the ADC and estimating the propragation delay on the PCB

Comment: do you know of any application note that contains a worked example with all the different quantities that must be known and used in the calculation?

Comment: "the PCB delay from the oscillator to the clock pin of each component is different" -- Board designer should have constrained this to a known margin (datasheet ref), which has to be used as source latency timing constraint inside FPGA

Comment: @Quantum0xE7 There is an Intel/Altera document with an interesting example. Google "Intel Quartus Prime Timing Analyzer Cookbook". Go to page 9 and look at the example 12. The left of the block diagram is similar to yours

Answer (score 1):

I do not think the overall architecture is the best one.

How I would do it:

- clock ADC from the FPGA output pin,
- ADC to return back the data and clock (strobe) for FPGA to sample the data,
- synchronize data within FPGA between two clock domains - clock (strobe) returned by the ADC and FPGA internal clock.

In this setup, and proper PCB routing, you know the allowed slacks and all returning signals (control and data) come together.

Comment: See the ADC actually operates at a very high frequency. The datasheet of the ADC implies that it should not be fed from the FPGA clock pin but directly from the oscillator.

Comment: Link to datasheet? Part numbers?